# Creating trip cost calulator

Tags: java, if-statement, menu

I am working on an assignment for school and I have a basic program already that calculates the total cost of a trip by asking the total mileage, average mpg of car, and cost per gallon of gas.  This works great but I also need to add a few more items and I am unsure of how to do so.  First I need to include a menu of some sort giving the option to either calculate the trip cost or exit the program.  Next I need to incorporate somewhere in the program a bit asking if the user wants an oil change or not and then based on the answer adding this to the total.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GasCalculator {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many miles do you plan to travel?");
        int miles = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("So you will drive " + miles +" miles.");

        System.out.println("What is the price of gas?");
        double gas = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ok, so gas costs $" + gas +" per gallon.");

        System.out.println("What is the average MPG of your car? Use the nearest whole number.");
        int mpg = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("So, you get " + mpg +" miles per gallon.");

        System.out.println("Would you like an oil change? Enter Y or N");


        double cost = (miles / mpg * gas + oil);

        System.out.println("Below is your total cost");
        System.out.println(String.format("Your trip will cost $" + cost + "."));

    }
}
```

As you can see I added a little bit asking if they want an oil change. My vision of doing it would be to create a variable for either the y or n answer and then an if else statement based on whether y or n. If y it will add 39.99 to a new variable "oil". If n it will make the variable 0. Oil has been incorporated into the final equation regardless of it's value for ease.

I am not looking for anyone to do my assignment for me. I guess I am looking to see what this would look like or if anyone has any input as far as how I should tackle this. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: If you ask a question about Java, you should add [java] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GasCalculator {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {

        double total = 0;       

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many miles do you plan to travel?");
        int miles = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("So you will drive " + miles +" miles.");

        System.out.println("What is the price of gas?");
        double gas = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Ok, so gas costs $" + gas +" per gallon.");

        System.out.println("What is the average MPG of your car? Use the nearest whole number.");
        int mpg = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("So, you get " + mpg +" miles per gallon.");

        System.out.println("Would you like an oil change? Enter Y or N");
        char oil = scan.next().charAt(0);
        if (Character.toUpperCase(oil) == 'Y'){
            System.out.println("Cost of oil change id 39.99);
            System.out.println("39.99 will be added to your total cost");
            total += 39.99;
        }

        double cost = (miles / mpg * gas);
        total += cost;

        String menu = "Pick a menu option: \n"
                      + "1. Calculate total \n"
                      + "2. exit";

        System.out.println(menu);
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1){
            System.out.println("Below is your total cost");
            System.out.println(String.format("Your trip will cost $" + total + "."));
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get your version of the program running like you want it to?

Comment: If you enter 2 from the menu, you shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: I am still working on getting it together. unfortunately time is not my friend lol

Comment: So for this option I would create another class to run the total calculation?

Comment: No, everything goes, in your `main` method. Let me give you an example. Let's say you're at an ATM machine. You put in your card, it gives you an option menu. Say you pick check balance. It returns your balance, then asks you if you want another transaction. In order for this be accomplished, the program need to be in a loop. Anything you want in that menu should be inside the loop. Anything you only want to occur once, goes outside the loop. I suggest you write down exactly what you want your program to do, figure out what you want in the menu options, and use my template to work off of.

Comment: All you need to do is add whatever menu option you want to the String. Everytime an option has executed, the menu pops back up, until the user hit the number command to stop the loop.

Comment: Ok so I would include the part where I get the miles and gas price and all that in the area before the menu begins?

Also I tried to compile and run your stuff but I get an error saying int input= scanner.nextInt(); cannot find symbol

Comment: Nevermind about the error. scanner needed to be changed to scan.

Comment: I apologize for confusing you with the loop. I didn't really understand your question. There is really no need for a loop, since your program should not be looping. See my edit for a solution to your problem.

Comment: I ended up actually moving the pieces for the total (mileage, mpg, gas price) right between the string menu and the print menu. Works perfectly thank you so much!!

Comment: No worries. Had to make up for messing with yourhead :)

Answer (score 2):

> First I need to include a menu of some sort giving the option to
>   either calculate the trip cost or exit the program.

You can use a [switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) statement.

```
//ask for user to enter 0 to exit, 1 to calculate the trip

switch(answer) {
     case 0 : System.exit(0);
              break;
     case 1 : //calculate cost trip here
              break;
     default : System.exit(0);
}
```

> Next I need to incorporate somewhere in the program a bit asking if
>   the user wants an oil change or not and then based on the answer
>   adding this to the total

Well you can get the value of the user with your `Scanner` object like you did and write an if statement to check this value.

```
System.out.println("Would you like an oil change? Enter Y or N");
//here get the value of the user using your scanner object
double oil = 0;
if(/*test if value is equals to y*/)
    oil += 39.99;
```

---

Hints :

1. to avoid testing if the value is `"y"` or `"Y"`, use the method [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) of the `String` class.
2. when this will works you can wrap the functionnality of calculating the trip cost in a method and call this method in the case 1 of the switch statement.

Comment: How would I use my scanner object to do this? I'm sorry I'm new to all this and syntax of this stuff is really messing me up.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement exit option like this:

```
System.out.println("Choose your desired option:\n1)Calculate Trip Cost\n2)Exit");
int answer = scan.nextInt();

if (answer==1){
    // the rest of your program
    System.out.println("How many miles do you plan to travel?");
    int miles = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("So you will drive " + miles +" miles.");

    System.out.println("What is the price of gas?");
    double gas = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Ok, so gas costs $" + gas +" per gallon.");

    System.out.println("What is the average MPG of your car? Use the nearest whole number.");
    int mpg = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("So, you get " + mpg +" miles per gallon.");

    System.out.println("Would you like an oil change? Enter Y or N");


    double cost = (miles / mpg * gas + oil);

    System.out.println("Below is your total cost");
    System.out.println(String.format("Your trip will cost $" + cost + "."));
}
```